# jquery mobile multi-column scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, ibm-mobilefirst, dojo, worklight-studio

Does JQuery have an equivalent to Dojo's scrollview?  I want to have multiple panes scrolling independently on a worklight tablet application.  I tried iscroll-view but it scrolls the whole screen rather than just a single content pane.

In the mobile browser simulator it works find and the scrolling is nice and smooth.  however, when I run it on an actual iPad v2 it scrolls the whole page and even scrolls the headers and nav bar at the bottom.

Comment: Could you share your HTML content, to see how you have implemented so far and if any improvements can be done to your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following from [Scroll JQuery Mobile Panel Separately From Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305488/scroll-jquery-mobile-panel-separately-from-content) - it works for us for a panel as navigation.

```
    /*-------------------Styling for Nav Panel Scrolling Independent from Content:START--------------------------*/

 .ui-panel.ui-panel-open {
        position:fixed;
    }
 .ui-panel-inner {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0px;
        overflow: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }


 /*-------------------Styling for Nav Panel Scrolling Independent from Content:END--------------------------*/
```

Comment: This worked a treat for me.  I had tried the iScroll but on the iPad (intended target) this worked even better.  I've seen some issues where I needed to initiate the scrolling with a two finger swipe rather than one.  I will investigate further to ensure that it works as required.

Answer (score 0):

JqueryMobile roadmap http://jquerymobile.com/roadmap/ says independent scolling should arrive in version 1.7

As a hack workaround maybe adding the divs via an iframe may offer a clumsy solution.