# $.scrollTo doesn't work with position:fixed;

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a jqm page with a panel.  And I want the panel to scroll to a certain position.
Using the $scrollTo plugin works, but it scrolls both the panel and the page itself.

```
$('#myPanel').on('panelopen',PanelOpen)
function PanelOpen(myEvent, myUI ) {
    $.scrollTo('#ID498',1000)
}
```

[Here's my example](http://www.phillipsenn.com/Matrix/jqm/PanelScrollTo/PanelScrollTo.cfm) showing it scroll the panel (hooray), and the page (boo).

Now, from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305488/scroll-jquery-mobile-panel-separately-from-content), I was able to make the panel scrollable:

```
#myPanel .ui-panel.ui-panel-open {
    position:fixed;
}
#myPanel .ui-panel-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

But now the $.scrollTo plugin doesn't work. Here's [my second example](http://www.phillipsenn.com/Matrix/jqm/PanelScrollTo/PanelScrollable.cfm), this time with the panel scrollable, but I can no longer position it using JavaScript.

Comment: If you want panel to scroll only, `overflow-y: scroll;` should fix it. However it doesn't work on Android. To fix a panel, add `data-position-fixed="true"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to call the scrollTo() on the inner panel div which is actually set to overflow and it will work:

```
function PanelOpen(myEvent, myUI ) {
    $("#myPanel .ui-panel-inner").scrollTo('#ID498',1000)
}
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/96Smp/)**

Comment: this is fantastic!  Q: How did you import my page into jsfiddle? Did you copy/paste my code or is there a tool to point jsfiddle to a url and have it import everything?

Comment: I just copied the relevant code and links manually. I don't know of any tool to automate this.